# how to track the time duration video played in ipad app

Tags: iphone, ios, video

I have ipad app in which i play video i want that when user plays video if it view video 2 seconds then it should show alert the time how much time user viewed video or duration

here is the code i am using for playing video.

```
            [[mp moviePlayer] prepareToPlay];
    [[mp moviePlayer] setUseApplicationAudioSession:NO];
    [[mp moviePlayer] setShouldAutoplay:YES];
    [[mp moviePlayer] setControlStyle:2];
    //[[mp moviePlayer] setRepeatMode:MPMovieRepeatModeOne];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];
```

Answer (score 1):

MPMoviePlayerController generates notifications to keep your app informed about the state of movie playback.

1, When the movie player begins playing, is paused, or begins seeking forward or backward
2, When AirPlay playback starts or ends. For details please [click here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Use the notifications and gather the currentPlaybackTime property, and the video duration property for further calculations.

```
- (void)MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if ((player.loadState & MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK) == MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK)
    {
        NSLog(@"content play length is %g seconds", player.duration);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was in the middle of writing this answer. +1

Comment: i am writing this code but it gives error loadstate not found

Comment: Here is the doc http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPMoviePlayerController/loadState

Comment: can you please edit here i am just calling this method as you have given

Comment: Make sure that you declared a class variable player. It is an object of MPMoviePlayerController.

Comment: how i declare that in h file

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;

Answer (score 0):

You can record the start date and end date, then compare the date to see how long the video was played.

Date includes time too.

So:

1) When user presses play, you can go:

```
NSDate *startPlayDate = [NSDate date];
```

2) When user stops the video, you can go:

```
NSDate *stopPlayDate = [NSDate date];
```

3) Now compare the difference in the two dates, you should see how many seconds the user played the video for:

```
NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents* components = [gregorianCalendar components: NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit
                                                    fromDate:startPlayDate 
                                                      toDate:stopPlayDate 
                                                     options:0] ;

NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Video played for: %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds", components.hour, components.minute, components.second];

UIAlert *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Duration"
                                            message:message
                                           delegate:self
                                       cancelButton:@"OK"
                                        otherButton:nil, nil];

[alert show];
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The `currentPlaybackTime` property in the `MPMediaPlayback` protocol gives you that info.

Have a look at the `currentPlaybackTime` property of the `MPMediaPlayback` protocol. `MPMoviePlayerController` adheres to that protocol, hence you can use it directly on any instance of that class.

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [...];
[...]
NSLog(@"current time: %g", player.currentPlaybackTime);
From the MPMediaPlayback Reference;
```

currentPlaybackTime
The current position of the playhead.

```
@property(nonatomic) NSTimeInterval currentPlaybackTime
```

Comment: i am using like this but it gives error         NSLog(@"current time: %g", mp.currentPlaybackTime);

Comment: currenPlayBackTime not found of a object MPMoviePlayerViewController

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [MPMediaPlayback Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller_class/Reference/Reference.html).

> **currentPlaybackTime**: For content streamed live from a server, this value represents the time from the beginning of the playlist when it was first loaded.